# Python ouput to a file without return

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, output

Is there any way to output to a file without having a return value?

Here are my functions:

```
#Function that prints the overall company information for the outfile
def details():
    return "Company Name: %s\nNumber of Employees: %d employee(s)\n" % (company, len(employees))

#Function that outputs the employees by department for the outfile
def deps():
    for department in dep_tup:
        total = len(dep_dict[department])
        print("%s with %d employee(s)" % (dep_dict[department][0]["em_department"], total))
        for i in range(total):
            print("%s: %s, %s, $%.2f per year" % (dep_dict[department][i]["name"], dep_dict[department][i]["position"], dep_dict[department][i]["em_department"], dep_dict[department][i]["salary"]))

#Function for the output file
def outfile():
    f = open("output.txt", "w")
    f.write(details())
    f.write("\nEmployees by Department List\n")
    f.write(deps())
    f.close()
```

However, the f.write(deps()) statement doesn't run because the function deps() returns None. I tried using return statements intead of print but then it doesn't do what I need it to do. Any other options?

Comment: The fact that `deps()` returns `None` does _not_ stop `f.write(deps())` from running - but it does stop it from _completing_ successfully because `write()` raises an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your function deps() return the value you want written like you did with `details()`

```
def details():
    return "Company Name: %s\nNumber of Employees: %d employee(s)\n" % (company, len(employees))

f.write(details())
```

However, I think you want this to write multiple lines.  In that case, it might be better to pass the file to your function as an argument, and call write() in your function:

```
#Function that outputs the employees by department for the outfile
def deps(f):
    for department in dep_tup:
        total = len(dep_dict[department])
        f.write("%s with %d employee(s)" % (dep_dict[department][0]["em_department"], total))
        for i in range(total):
            f.write("%s: %s, %s, $%.2f per year" % (dep_dict[department][i]["name"], dep_dict[department][i]["position"], dep_dict[department][i]["em_department"], dep_dict[department][i]["salary"]))

#Function for the output file
def outfile():
    f = open("output.txt", "w")
    f.write(details())
    f.write("\nEmployees by Department List\n")
    deps(f)
    f.close()
```